# i cannot able to see the file in system 32 folder

Tags: windows-7

I copied one  file in system 32 folder , that file gets copied in that folder but the problem is unable to seen in that folder , so i paste the file again its ask for replace  just overwrite the file but again the file is not shown same problem persists
 In windows 7 professional
 64 bit

Comment: More detail and some screenshots if possible would be nice.

Comment: Ask more clearly please. One 3-line sentence is hard to read.

Comment: sir actually i copied one xml file from share folder to system 32 folder, the file gets copied in that folder without issue ,but the problem is that copied file is not shown in that folder even i try to search that file but unable to find . so i decide to paste the file again in that folder this time its shows warning that is (Do you want to overwrite the file) i just overwrite the file and see in system 32 folder but unable to found . please let me know any other solution

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a hidden file. Open 'Folder Options' and check 'Show hidden files, folders and drives' under the View tab.

Also, press F5 to reload your folder after copying the file.

Comment: no its a normal file and i check show hidden files and folders and press f5 and try but no change remains same .please let me know any other